# Flutter When I add google maps it doesn't load as on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

[image]

I add google maps, it looks like this on ios and android, I did the necessary actions in the necessary API and manifest files
package used : flutter_google_maps

Comment: There is any error in debug console?

Comment: Have you add `onMapCreated` callback and initialize `GoogleMapController` with initial `CameraPosition`?

Comment: check have you add google map key in android manifest file?